# Should we create a canonical iCloud Q&A question?

Tags: discussion

We are getting more and more questions about iCloud, and if you go through the [icloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icloud) you will find a lot of them relate to people misunderstanding iCloud and how it works, including backup.

On SU we handle these by creating a canonical question which we can use to close all these questions and not have to repeat the answers.

(I have answered a few of these and I often copy and paste from my previous answers)

Thoughts? Ideas? Should we do it?

Comment: I can't seem to find this canonical question, can you add a link? Anyway, if this solution helped you in [su], it should also be useful here.

Comment: @LoïcWolff There isn't one specifically for the iCloud, but we have them for networking issue, what do when you get a virus, etc.

Comment: I'd love to see one for "Help! My computer doesn't work!" -- and an answer that explains what kind of information is helpful to include so people can actually answer the question. Then we can close uninformative questions of this variety as duplicates, which will point to the tips on what information is actually needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a good idea for certain components of iCloud, but I think that doing one question for iCloud as a whole might be sub-optimal as iCloud isn't really a single thing but a collection of separate cloud-based services.

So having a canonical question for mail, contacts, and calendar might be nice, and a separate one for documents, and a separate one for App Store and iBookstore, and one for iTunes, etc. might be the best approach.